# Ruby : select specific element of a parsed json

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, parsing

I am trying to parse a specific part of my JSON with Ruby.
I'm getting this string from the server :

```
[   {
    "id": 1,
    "player_id": "not_this_one\n",
    "highscore": 23   },   {
    "id": 2,
    "player_id": "id_to_get\n",
    "highscore": 44   },   {
    "id": 3,
    "player_id": "not_this_one_either\n",
    "highscore": 278   } ]
```

And I want to extract the highscore of the second player whose "played_id" match with the string "id_to_get".

I managed to code that :

```
response = HTTPLite.get("http://some-api")
if response[:status] == 200
  parsed = HTTPLite::JSON.parse(response[:body])
  p parsed[0]
end
```

Which outputs the first part of my json, i.e :  "{ "id": 1, "player_id": "not_this_one\n", "highscore": 23 }"

How can I change the [0] to extract specifically the json part I want to ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `parsed.dig(1, "highscore")` or `parsed.find { |parsed_i| parsed_i["player_id"] == "id_to_get\n" }["highscore"]`?

Answer (score 2):

`parsed[0]` is returning the 1st item in your `parsed` array.  If you want to return the second item you can use `parsed[1]`.

However you might not know the order of the array, so you can check for the `player_id` you want.

```
parsed.find {|x| x[:player_id] == "id_to_get\n" }
```